# Spring MVC ignoring servlet configuration when rendering pages

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I wrote a REST API as a Spring Boot application, and after I got that working tried to add a web front-end, starting with a basic "Hello World" type index page. Attempts to hit the home page consistently result in the following message:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Here is the controller (which I've verified is being hit via breakpoints):

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Here is the main application with the view resolver, which does seem to be incorporated based on that message:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.name.api.repositories")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.name.api.controllers",
        })
@EntityScan("com.name.api.entities")
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/views/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

As you saw, the name in the message is always "dispatcherServlet", which is invariant even if I rename the servlets above.

I also have a dispatcher-servlet.xml, which I doubt is being used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
<mvc:default-servlet-handler></mvc:default-servlet-handler>
</beans>
```

There is an index.html file as well as an index.jsp one underneath WebContent/WEB-INF/ (the folder created when I added the dynamic web page facet to my project). It persistently fails to find them, even if I copy WEB-INF to its own folder on the same level as WebContent rather than beneath it (or if WEB-INF is copied under src/main/webapp/). I've stepped through with a debugger and found that the message gets printed when it fails to find a handler mapping, but I suspect that is too far down into the nitty-gritty when the name of the servlet doesn't correspond to what's in the configuration (and even deliberately adding in malformed xml to the file makes no difference, although that could be just the compiler not replacing good code with bad once it recognizes errors). Adding the same `<load-on-startup>` tag to the "jsp" servlet also does nothing.

This seems like a rather basic error and I'm sure someone else here has asked it and had it answered, but I've gone through lots of similar questions here and none of the solutions seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred choice is to work with spring bean XML configuration files instead of Java based configuration, so my explanation is using my preferred choice. you can afterward to the necessary "translations".

I believe you're missing a few configurations:

1. When the dispatcher servlet is being loaded for the first time, it'll look for a spring bean configuration file name: `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, If your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` is not under `/WEB-INF/` as it expects, then you should configure that. Let's say for example that it's found under `/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml`, then in your `web.xml` you should to this:

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>contextLocation</param-name>
           <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   ```
2. Within your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file you need to provide configuration how to support your web-mvc application. In that file you'll provide beans configuration to "live" in your  web application context, that will give control over the requset processing in your spring-mvc project.

With that being said, just add the next lines in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

- `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in order to have spring web-mvc annotations support in your project, such as: `@Controller` & `@RequestMapping`, plus it'll give you other spring web mvc features support such as Data Binding, Custom Validation, etc'
- `<context:component-scan base-package="org.your.controller.package" />` this will tell the IOC container where exactly your controllers are located within your project.
- Put your view resolver within the `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, that view resolver bean should exist under the web application context. for eaxmple:

  ```
  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>
  ```

***In your case you put the view resolver bean not within web application context as expected, you kind of have a mixture of all your "living" beans inside one context. and of course, you're missing the configurations mention already***

Comment: dispatcher-servlet.xml is under WEB-INF, but like I said I doubt it's actually getting read. The @Controller type annotations are already being used by my REST API, as well as the HomeController I included as my first bit of code. My RestApiApplication already tells the program in which packages to find the controllers, repositories etc, and that stuff works. It's the xml stuff which isn't getting read. I've tried extending AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer to duplicate the xml, but a debugger showed none of its functions get called.